# How to bind a JQuery change event to image map click

Tags: jquery

I need help troubleshooting some JQuery code that breaks when a user changes muscle groups by clicking on an image map in my Rails 4 application.  Some background:  The image map is of the human muscular system. The target muscle groups and strength exercises are in separate drop-down menus, which work okay. The hotspots on the image map also work okay.

My goal is to improve user experience by letting users click hotspots on the image map to choose target muscle groups. I'm using JQuery to filter option elements by optgroup. For example, if a user clicks the "abs" region on the image map, the first drop-down menu should indicate the user's muscle group selection, and the second drop-down menu should populate with abs-related exercises.  My JQuery works okay until a user changes muscle groups by clicking the image map.  That's when the exercise drop-down menu stops populating.

Form fields for drop-down menus:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :muscle_group %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :muscle_group_id, MuscleGroup.order(:name), :id, :name, prompt: "Choose your target muscles", include_blank: false %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :strength_exercise %><br />
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :strength_training_list_id, MuscleGroup.order(:name), :strength_training_lists, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

The rendered HTML for drop-down menus:

```
<div class="field">
  <label class="string required" for="strength_exercise_muscle_group"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Muscle group</label><br>
  <select id="strength_exercise_muscle_group_id" name="strength_exercise[muscle_group_id]"><option value="">Choose your target muscles</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="11">Abs - rectus abdominis</option>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <label class="string optional" for="strength_exercise_strength_exercise">Strength exercise</label><br />
  <select id="strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id" name="strength_exercise[strength_training_list_id]"><option value=""></option>
  <optgroup label="Abs - rectus abdominis">
  <option value="5">Lying Leg Raise</option>
  <option value="6">Kneeling Front Pull Down</option>
  <option value="15">Bicycle</option>
  <option value="24">Ab Roll-out</option>
  // more option values ...
  </optgroup>
  </select>   
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#map_abs").click(function(){
        var absID = 11;
        var muscle_group = $("#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id option[value='" + absID + "']").attr("selected","selected");
        var strength_training_lists = $('#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id').html();
        var options;
        var muscle_group_selected = $('#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id :selected').text();
        options = $(strength_training_lists).filter("optgroup [label='" + muscle_group_selected + "']").html();
        console.log(options);
          if (options) {
          $('#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id').html(options);
            return $('#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id').parent().show();
         } else {
            $('#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id').empty(); 
           return $('#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id').parent().hide();
        }
       }); //end click function
  });  //end ready
```

This is what happens after the page loads:

If a user clicks on the abs hotspot, the first drop-down menu correctly indicates that "abs" is the selected option for the muscle group. The second drop-down menu correctly populates with abs related strength exercises.  This is the desired behavior anytime a user clicks a hotspot.

This is what happens if a user uses the image map to change from one muscle group to another one:

My JQuery code breaks on the change.  If a user uses the image map to change 
from one muscle group to another, say from abs to biceps, the first drop-down menu correctly changes to indicate biceps is the newly selected option, but the second drop-down menu disappears.  No biceps exercises are shown.  In the console, the variable named "options" is "undefined" after the attempted change.  The options variable is empty, because of the break in my code's logic.

The following behavior is what I want to see whenever a user clicks the image map to change muscle groups:

(a)  the first dropdown menu should indicate the new muscle group selected, and
(b)  the second drop-down menu should populate with exercises that target the new muscle group.

My thought is to bind a JQuery change event to the selector '#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id' to deal with when a user changes muscle groups. Something like:

```
$('#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id').change(function() {
 //code to address what happens when user changes muscle groups
}
```

However, I'm new to Jquery and confused about how to do this, in particular  the syntax and where to place such a function if that is indeed what I really need to fix my code.  How do I modify my JQuery code to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could just call the click function in your `.change` function:

```
$('#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id').change(function() {
   var bodyPart = // distinguish your body part from the id
   $(bodyPart).click();
}
```

Like this both changes will use the same method.

EDIT: See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3w70d59/) for a demo!

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not sure how to do what you are suggesting.. Could you edit your answer to show how I might do this in the context of my existing JQuery code.  Also, where in my existing code would I place the change function?

Comment: @codeinspired Take a look at the jsfiddle in the question :)

Comment: I'm still stuck trying to get a change function to work in my code. I'm getting the same behavior as I reported in my original post.  My code still breaks when a user clicks on a new hotspot. I think I'm confused about two things: (a) what to put inside the change function to cause it to do what I desire; and, (b) where exactly to put the change function in my existing code. I think I'm close, but stuck on figuring out the syntax and placement of the change function. I'm learning JavaScript/jQuery. I need to do more research.

Comment: @codeinspired a) In the change function you must trigger the click of the right element, i.e. if `id == 11` you should trigger the click on `#map_abs`, if `id == 12` you need to trigger the corresponding image. b) The change function should be in the place it is in the jsfiddle, in the `$(document).ready(function() { // Here }`

Comment: I understand what I need to do for the change function now.  Thanks!  My program already has a CoffeeScript with a change function that is bound to #strength_exercise_muscle_group_id. It handles the drop-down menu that users can use (instead of an image map click) to change muscle groups. Now I need to determine how to integrate those two change functions, which are bound to the same element. That's a different issue from my original question. You've answered the scope of my original question. I will accept your answer, and continue to work on my "new" problem. I'm still learning ;).

Comment: @codeinspired Cheers! Good luck and happy coding :)